# how to avoid using time.sleep() function in automated testing

Tags: python, automated-tests

When I try to using a python automator testing framwork to test QQ login on phone,  I find that people like to use time.sleep(second) between two operations. I understand the goal of such way, but I want to konw if there have a better way to handle page load between to operations, because a fixed sleep time is not flexible, and sometimes it causes time westing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try mocking `time.sleep`?

Comment: I am sorry to make you think so. I just want a new way!